# Confused with the construction of cylindrical set measures - abstract Wiener space

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, wiener-measure, gaussian-measure

I was reading the Wikipedia page on [Abstract Wiener spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Wiener_space) to get some intuition on the Cameron-Martin spaces. I am really confused with their definition of the "measure" defined on cylindrical sets on a Hilbert space $H$.

1. Why is this well defined?
2. The article claims that if the Hibert space $H$ is densely embedded into a sufficiently larger separable Banach Space $B$, the same construction can be extended to a (countably-additive) measure on the cylindrical sets of $B$. However, it also claims that $H$ has measure 0, even though the measure is defined by taking the intersection of cylindrical sets in $B$ with $H$.

Any clarification is much appreciated (as well as references).

Thank you!

[image]
[image]